# How can I speed up a slow ArcGIS Server 10.2 - PostgreSQL (9.2) ST_Intersects query?

Tags: postgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, postgresql, performance

I am troubleshooting a slow st_geometry query in Postgres 9.2 that uses [ST_Intersects](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/ST_Intersects/006z00000059000000/)--a basic Select from table where ST_Intersects type query.

```
                         table_extent                         |                          queryshape_extent
--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
 BOX(-10942448.8275 5798114.3628,-10937877.2752 5800427.4828) | BOX(-10942696.568988 5797982.903128,-10941159.336747 5798715.800428)
(1 row)

Time: 1086.008 ms
```

ArcGIS featureclass (world behrmann - 54017):

```
CREATE TABLE fe.xx_test_4
(
  objectid integer NOT NULL,
  operation_id integer NOT NULL,
  shape st_geometry
)
```

I also recreated the table and spatial index with PostGIS geometry for comparison, using the same tablespace configuration.

```
CREATE TABLE fe.xx_test_5
(
  objectid integer,
  operation_id integer,
  geom geometry
)
```

The featureclass(st_geometry) query takes **23** seconds to run and returns **317490** rows (from a total of **1031123** rows).  I wasn't sure if this was explainable by the fact that I'm returning 30% of the rows.

Query:

```
select 
operation_id
from 
fe.xx_test_4 a,
(select st_geometry(
'POLYGON ((-10942387.005869 5798694.633719,-10942175.338779 5798684.050364,-10942003.359269 5798684.050364,-10941714.962859 5798697.279557,-10941580.025089 5798705.217073,-10941378.941353 5798715.800428,-10941177.857618 5798543.820917,-10941159.336747 5798194.570218,-10941328.670419 5798096.674189,-10941542.983348 5797982.903128,-10941791.692179 5797998.778160,-10942000.713430 5798009.361515,-10942151.526232 5798019.944869,-10942437.276803 5798019.944869,-10942561.631219 5798041.111578,-10942625.131346 5798062.278287,-10942693.923150 5798120.486737,-10942696.568988 5798308.341279,-10942641.006377 5798440.633211,-10942588.089605 5798580.862658,-10942532.526994 5798665.529494,-10942503.422769 5798689.342041,-10942418.755933 5798697.279557,-10942387.005869 5798694.633719))'
,55) shape) b
where sde.ST_Intersects(a.shape,  b.shape)
```

-

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..24.79 rows=5 width=4) (actual time=0.168..26826.593 rows=317490 loops=1)
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using xx_test_4_sx on xx_test_4 a  (cost=0.00..24.72 rows=5 width=36) (actual time=0.143..24439.164 rows=317490 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (shape ^! ('C1000000180000000800100037000000A50200000100000095D3C7DCDE03A1A49F8BD307FCE0269B9D03CDAD67D0D809E2C323ED881DEAE943CCAD67D0CC40F93FF01E9F50CB1CCAF02DFB01399CE8502AFF08A0199DACE0190C077F9CD169BAAAA03D6BBF501B3F7D101D5BBF501E9F50CC2DCA401CFD809FC85E002C49310F3F7D10100FFB08202A9F50C00000000'::st_geometry))
 Total runtime: 27934.344 ms
(5 rows)
```

If I run the same query against the PostGIS table, it completes in 2.7 seconds:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on xx_test_5 a  (cost=19436.28..131296.02 rows=105119 width=4)
   Recheck Cond: (geom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geometry)
   Filter: _st_intersects(geom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geometry)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on xx_test_5_sx  (cost=0.00..19410.00 rows=315359 width=0)
         Index Cond: (geom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geometry)
```

This is the query executed against the PostGIS table:

```
select 
operation_id
from 
xx_test_5 a
where ST_Intersects(a.geom,  ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON ((...values...));
```

I also tried setting  the `enable_seqscan=false` on the st_geometry query, which changed the explain plan but not the execution time (still around 23 seconds):

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on victor quebec  (cost=24764.850..60721.270 rows=329794 width=4)
    Recheck Cond: (kilo ^! 'five'::seven)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mike  (cost=0.000..24682.400 rows=329794 width=0)
          Index Cond: (kilo ^! 'five'::seven)
```

http://explain.depesz.com/s/dI37

How can I get the st_geometry query to perform like the postgis query?

Comment: Try running: `select 
operation_id
from 
xx_test_5 a, (Select ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON ((...values...))') as geom) b
where ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) ;` The planner has an easier job when it sees your polygon coming from a 2nd table that can then be spatially joined, rather than it being created inside the ST_Intersecs function.

Comment: If the storage is PostGIS, why is your title "SDE"?

Comment: The storage for the actual table is in st_geometry--I created the PostGIS table for troubleshooting.  The PostGIS table is good, but I can't use PostGIS storage (see http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/138842/31 ).

Comment: Spatial-first query on 30% of a million-row query isn't ever going to be optimal.  You should always prefix Esri ST operators with "sde."

Comment: @JohnBarça: no luck on the st_geometry table.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what an ST_Geometry table means -- is this some ArcGIS thing?. But, I know with Postgres/Postgis, writing the polygon as a separate table versus creating it inside ST_Intersects can lead to orders of magnitude improvements. I found out the hard way :D

Comment: I think I need to clear things up in my question!  The performance issue is with a table using st_geometry (Esri) as the storage type.  When I re-created the table with postgis storage type, it was pretty good (as good as can be expected when selecting out 30% of the rows spatially).

Comment: While you clean up the question, be sure to use the correct product name (it hasn't been called "SDE" since 8.0 was released fifteen years ago)

Comment: This question still needs more detail -- What is the extent (MBR) of the table?  What is the extent of the constraint shape? What options were used to create the spatial index? How spatially fragmented is the table?

Comment: The featureclass was loaded in ArcCatalog (so no options other than create/delete), which results in a GIST index.  I did change the tablespace of the spatial index (to a faster disk).

Comment: I don't have a number on the spatial fragmentation, but it isn't fragmented much on the test dataset (but it has potential to become fragmented).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current workaround is to build a side table with 2 columns, the objectid and geometry( as PostGIS geometry). And to maintain that table with triggers on the featureclass.  Then perform spatial queries against the side table and join back to the featureclass.

<s>I have an open incident with Esri, but so far, no luck. I will update this answer if/when we make some progress on this front.</s>

I just received an Esri Bug ID for this issue: BUG-000088734. Esri was able to reproduce the poor performance on the st_geometry data type (*at a much smaller set of records than what I was using*).  Users with smaller databases can probably absorb the performance hit (I didn't notice it until my table was several million records).